# Server client communication Node.js

Tags: node.js, client, arduino

I have written a server program  server.js as below

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4", {
baudrate: 9600
 });
 serialPort.on("open", function () {
  console.log('open');
   serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
console.log('data received: ' + data);
});  
  serialPort.write("ls\n", function(err, results) {
  console.log('err ' + err);
   console.log('results ' + results);
//io.sockets.emit('message', 'data');
     }); 
     }); 
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
// If socket.io receives message from the client browser then 
// this call back will be executed.
socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
// If a web browser disconnects from Socket.IO then this callback is called.
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('disconnected');
});
});

  var cleanData = ''; // this stores the clean data
  var readData = '';  // this stores the buffer
  serialPort.on('data', function (data) { // call back when data is received
  readData += data.toString(); // append data to buffer
  // if the letters 'A' and 'B' are found on the buffer then isolate what's in the middle
  // as clean data. Then clear the buffer. 
  if (readData.indexOf('B') >= 0 && readData.indexOf('A') >= 0) {
    cleanData = readData.substring(readData.indexOf('A') + 1, readData.indexOf('B'));
    readData = '';
    io.sockets.emit('message', cleanData);

     }
 });
```

The client side program is (index.html)

```
<html>
    </head>
        <link type="text/css" href="/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script>

            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
            socket.on('connect', function () {
                socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                    // Convert value to integer
                    var val = ((parseInt(msg) / 1023)*100);

                    // Put sensor value to the 'sensor_value' span
                    $('#sensor_value').html(val);

                    });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div role="main">
            Potentiometer Value: <span id="sensor_value"></span><br/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using WAMP as web server
The server console is giving me the required output. But nothing is coming in the webpage index.html

Comment: Have you already trying logging something inside the socket.on('message', function(msg)) to see if you're receiving the message of the socket?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://danieldvork.in/arduino-controlled-html5-etch-a-sketch-using-node-js-and-websockets/) you can find a tutorial showing exactly what you're trying to do: create a Node.js server and forwarding data from serial port to an html page via Websockets.

It was very useful to me when doing the same, sure it will help.